# Unable to edit SVG using Batik in Java?

Tags: java, xml, svg, batik

I have a student card SVG that has name, id and other field that I want to edit through Java, as the user inputs them using GUI.

I have successfully parsed the SVG using Batik but I can't see the changes that I made in SVG file when I open it.

```
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory f = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
String uri = "card.svg";
try {
    Document doc = f.createDocument(uri);
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getChildNodes();
    Element svg = doc.getElementById("name");
    svg.setTextContent("Your Name");
    System.out.println(svg.getTextContent());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I print out one the of SVG element's value using

`System.out.println(svg.getTextContent());`

It's changed but when I open the SVG in notepad it's the same.

**SVG**

```
<text x="759" y="361" id="name" class="fil3 fnt3">STUDENT</text>
```

**UPDATE FOR OTHERS: Solved with**

```
File file = new File("new.svg");
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(file);
XmlWriter.writeXml(svg, fWriter, false);
// Most crucial part, It wasn't working just because of flush
fWriter.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aren't using any particular SVG features here, just some generic XML parsing.  The result of parsing the document with `createDocument` is a DOM in memory, but that doesn't automatically write out your changes to a file.  You'll have to do that explicitly.  [Using the `org.apache.batik.svggen.XmlWriter` class is one of serializing.](http://mcc.id.au/2007/09/batik-course/#slide36)  You'll need to open a file for writing, and pass the `FileWriter` to it, along with the `Document` node.

Comment: FileOutputWriter ?

Comment: Sorry, FileWriter. (It's been a while since I've done any Java.)

Comment: Your Update #2 looks about right to me.  Please ask on the batik-users mailing list if you still have trouble.